# Recover Server 2008 R2 Domain Admin Password

Tags: passwords, windows

So I did the ultimate silly thing: I lost my domain admin password for my Server 2008 R2 box.

Sure, I could just re-install but that's going to be a huge pain. I tried rebooting with the Windows Install DVD and replacing `utilman.exe` with `cmd.exe`, but switching to `C:` displayed no files.

I can still log into the machine as a regular user, though.

And I see there's been some local privilege escalation vulnerabilities patched in the last couple months (specifically MS13-046 looks promising). And it's been a little while since I've logged in to apply MSFT patches (which oddly enough was what I was trying to log in to do).

Are there any publicly available exploits for these bugs? I don't see any in Metasploit. Or is there just a better way altogether? I full physical access to the machine, but I think BitLocker is enabled (which is why I think replacing utilman.exe failed).

Comment: Must the password be recovered or is resetting the password without ever learning what the old value was acceptable (I doubt it can be done due to your bitlocker use, but I just want the clarification in case someone besides me knows a way)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, sir resetting it is totally fine, too.  I just want to be able to log in again.  In fact, if we need to somehow add a new admin and delete the old one I think that'll be fine too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  No local admin access either. :-/

Comment: Last question, is this the domain controller or just a server on the domain.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sadly, it happens to be my Primary Domain Controller.

Comment: This is a great way to put a Blackhat question and make it look like an acceptable question.

Comment: @Adnan I should have known that it was you who made that comment! I find you all over SE, always enjoy your contributions (and I was thinking the same thing here, but I'm suspicious by nature).

Comment: @Adnan I didn't realize "blackhat" questions were off limits here, my apologies.  Nonetheless if there's a "whitehat" way to do it I'm more than open to that, it just seems like those are few and far between for this particular problem. :-/  I'm currently working on exploiting Tavis' bug (CVE-2013-3660), so this might be a moot point in a few hours anyway.

Comment: @Adnan You try, and succeed, not only here, on many SE sites. And world-at-large. I left a comment on your neglected but security-themed blog (well, title is security-themed) approx 11, or maybe 21 months ago.

Comment: @Adnan I think many questions here can be seen as disguised blackhat questions... And even if the guy turned out to be blackhat, we couldn't know that so noone can blame this site (or anyone in particular) for having helped to get his domain hacked, especially when he has not been applying patches.

Comment: FWIW I'd agree with @luc just because something could be misused doesn't mean it's not a legitimate question :) if that were the case then pretty much all pen-testing questions would be out of bounds...

Comment: @RoryMcCune I also agree. But this question boils down to "How can I haxor vulnerability X" which we always turn down almost immediately. Just because this one has some additional salt and pepper on it, doesn't mean we should give it any preferential treatment. We pounded the [iPad question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36748/) with 13 downvotes and a closure in less than 4 hours just for the mere suspicion that it's unethical. I guess behaviour like this would teach askers to just say _"my device"_ or _"my server"_ and be sure that we'd help them. `s/victim's/my/g` FTW

Comment: @Adnan I'll be honest, I'm a little surprised that this discussion is even happening.  It's a legitimate question, although I'm not sure how to prove it.  I deal with exploits regularly and it is my belief that using one in this case is the only way to achieve my desired result.  I'm open to being proven wrong, so if it makes the question more legitimate to you I can remove my suggestion of using an exploit.  But, let's be honest, that's a little silly, isn't it?

Comment: @mikhailzhan Buddy, you don't need to prove anything to me. This is how the community operates, everyone is entitled to their opinion. I've cast my close vote, and expressed my opinion, others have done the same. Just because I won't answer this question, doesn't mean others won't. I sincerely hope you find an answer and solve your problem. Finally, no, I don't think it's silly.

Comment: @Adnan ahh I missed the iPad one, or i'd have commented.  TBH I disagree with closing that and I'd disagree with closing this :) For me password recovery isn't a hacking scenario even if you end up using "hacking" tools to achieve the goal.  hmm might be an idea to put a question on meta to clarify ... :)

Comment: Is Bitlocker doing full disk encryption, or only secure boot? If it's only secure boot, there's probably a way to gain admin access by changing something outside the measured image by plugging the disk in another machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a local account but not a domain admin, IIRC you could try metasploit with the psexec payload to put meterpreter down on the server and then use the getsystem command to try and get admin on the box.

**EDIT Per @void_in** this won't work with W2K8 and UAC, to you'd need to use an exploit to elevate privileges, e.g. the MS12-042 one linked in comments

if that's succcessful you can dump the domain password hashes and try and crack them (this will be easier if you can remember anything about the password like length or character set that you did/did not include).

What I'm not sure about, but which might work is, if you can use getsystem on the domain controller whether you can then use meterpreters add user commands to add a new domain admin, may be worth a try :)

Comment: Just to clarify one point, getsystem won't work on Server 2008 due to UAC. First you will have to bypass the UAC through exploit/windows/local/bypassuac to use getsystem. The problem with that one is that bypassuac require Admin privileges, therefore, it is a lost cause from the start.

Comment: There is one vulnerability though that is going to give you SYSTEM privilege from a normal account. It is through exploiting ms12-042 Kernel Sysret vulnerability. The exploit is available at https://github.com/shjalayeri/sysret

Comment: I believe once I get local admin MSFT documents how I can reset the Domain Admin account (`net user ` something).  Also, the MS12-042 was patched.  It looks like the last time I installed patched on the machine was in November 2012. :-/